# How many starting credits do PCs receive?

Tags: character-creation, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

I've looked through the book multiple times but can't find where the default starting credits amount is for new PCs.

I know you can get bonus credits for additional obligation, but I simply am looking for a page citation on starting credits amount.

Comment: Even though the books are nice in terms of layout.......a few things just are quite hidden time and again (they really should have put up a 1 page character creation summary as example......even though there is not much to do there........it is quite spread out pagewise) , would make things like this easier.

Comment: @ThomasE. Yep I feel the same though I did find this gem that is basically that: xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/17190307/.../SW-EotE-Reference-Sheets-v2.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**New PCs start with 500 Credits**

> **Starting Gear**
>
> Player Characters in **Edge of the Empire** receive a budget of credits to spend on starting gear before gameplay begins. This budget is 500 credits, although it can be increased by undertaking additional obligation (see page 40). - p.97 *Edge of the Empire* - Core Rulebook - Character Creation

Answer (score 0):

You start with 500 credits.
You can also check out this thread:
https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/81328-starting-credits/